# Python dictionary to pairs and check for antisymmetry using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I am attempting to write three functions in python. The first accepts a list of ordered pairs as the input and turns that into a dictionary `pairs2dict`. The second turns a dictionary into a list of ordered pairs `dict2pairs`. The third accepts a relation represented as a dictionary for the input and returns true if the relation is antisymmetric and false otherwise `is_antisymmetric`. I think I interpret this as if `(key,value)` exists in the dictionary, then I must check that the pair `(value,key)` does not exist elsewhere in the dictionary keys/values.

I am very new to python and none of the codes that I have attempted so far are working. I have found some questions regarding turning a dictionary into ordered pairs, but it is for specific dictionaries, and I want to have a function that will work on any dictionary input. Here is a few sample inputs and outputs for each function:

```
relation1 = [(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (2,2)]
pairs2dict(relation1)
{0: [0, 1], 1:[1], 2: [1, 2]}
is_antisymmetric(relation1)
True

relation2 = {0: [1, 2], 1: [3, 4], 2: [2,3], 3: [ ], 4: [ ]}
dict2pairs(relation2)
[(0,1), (0,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,2), (2,3)]
is_antisymmetric(relation2)
True

relation3 = {'Jerry': ['George', 'Elaine'], 'Elaine':['Kramer']} 
dict2pairs(relation3)
[('Jerry', 'George'), ('Jerry', 'Elaine'), ('Elaine', 'Kramer')]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by anti symmetric? Can you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: In relation1 because pair (0,1) exists, I need to check to make sure that pair (1,0) does not exist in the dictionary in order for antisymmetry to be true. If (0,1) and (1,0) were both in the dictionary it would return false. But that is for a specific example, I want to be able to check this type of ordering for any given dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you solve this using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of list

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

---

For `pairs2dict`, we can use the `defaultdict`:

```
def pairs2dict(relation):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for item in relation:
        d[item[0]].append(item[1])
    return d

>>> relation1 = [(0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (2,1), (2,2)]
>>> pairs2dict(relation1)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: [0, 1], 1: [1], 2: [1, 2]})
>>> relation2 = pairs2dict(relation1)
```

---

For `dict2pairs`, we can use a `defaultdict` we got above, or use another normal dictionary as input in a list comprehension:

```
def dict2pairs(relation):
    return [(x, y) for x in relation for y in relation[x]]

>>> dict2pairs(relation2)
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
>>> relation2 = {0: [1, 2], 1: [3, 4], 2: [2,3], 3: [ ], 4: [ ]}
>>> dict2pairs(relation2)
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 2), (2, 3)]
```

---

For `is_antisymmetric`, a simple nested `for` loop should do the trick:

```
def is_antisymmetric(relation):
    for key, values in relation.iteritems():
        for value in values:
            if value in relation and key in relation[value]:
                return False
    return True

>>> relation2 = {0: [1, 2], 1: [3, 4], 2: [2,3], 3: [ ], 4: [ ]}
>>> is_antisymmetric(relation2)
False
>>> relation2 = pairs2dict(relation1)
>>> is_antisymmetric(relation2)
False
```

---

Note that your output for

```
relation3 = {'Jerry': ['George', 'Elaine'], 'Elaine':['Kramer']} 
dict2pairs(relation3)
[('Jerry', 'George'), ('Jerry', 'Elaine'), ('Elaine', 'Kramer')]
```

will not always be the same, because dicts are not ordered in python. (to order a dict, use `collections.OrderedDict`)

In fact, I get the output

```
>>> relation3 = {'Jerry': ['George', 'Elaine'], 'Elaine':['Kramer']} 
>>> dict2pairs(relation3)
[('Elaine', 'Kramer'), ('Jerry', 'George'), ('Jerry', 'Elaine')]
```

Where the elements are same but the order is different.

Comment: Thanks for your help. dict2pairs seems to work well, but antisymmetry isn't providing the correct results because relation 2 is actually antisymmetric. Also, I have to find a way without using the default dictionary for pairs2dict.  I appreciate the time for your response though!